# Wget download list of URL and set different file paths

Tags: wget

I read here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/ that if I want to download multiple URL's, I can save them in a text file like this

```
$ cat > download-file-list.txt
URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4
```

And use wget like this

```
$ wget -i download-file-list.txt
```

However suppose I want each URL to be saved in it's own directory on my drive, like this:

```
URL1 -> Users/Downloads/Tech
URL2 -> Users/Downloads/Fashion
URL3 -> Users/Downloads/Cooking
URL4 -> Users/Downloads/News
```

How do I accomplish this? Is it possible to manually set the directory for each URL in the text file and have wget read that and automatically know where to save each file? Is there any other methods to achieve what I need? I'm trying to setup and automated downloaded process using cronjobs later on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can't use that method.  The best way then would be a bash, perl, or python script that reads in a file in some format (maybe "URL directory") and downloads each url to the specified directory.  But you'll need to put some smarts outside of wget to get that behavior.

Comment: Oh I see... well alternatively is something like this feasible? Save a text file with contents like this `$ wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./Users/Downloads/Tech www.mozilla.org, $ wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./Users/Downloads/News www.gizmodo.com` and have a script that takes each line and executes it in terminal sequentially

Comment: Sure, it just means you'll have to edit the script if you want to add a site, rather than a data file.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I think I'll do. But I come from a web development background and has no knowledge of any unix scripts. What would you recommend would be good for this task. I'm looking at bash since its seems the easiest, but is it able to accomplish what I need?

Comment: This is pretty trivial, so I'd say bash is great.  Bash is good if you want to just run commands without any calculations or real flow.  If you need to do a lot of conditional logic or calculations, then its time to pull out a scripting language.

Comment: Yea my requirement is pretty much low level, take line, execute sequentially. Done. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a batch script that can do this, providing such a list :

```
$ cat > urllist.txt
URL1 file1
URL2 file2
URL3 file3
URL4 file4

$ while read url file; do 
    wget -c -O "$file" "$url"
done < urllist.txt
```

There should not be any space in URLs (they can be represented by %20) however, there can be spaces in the file name.

Comment: I believe last line is incomplete: `done < urllist.txt`