# Pulling Data From Two Different URLs Using Wget

Tags: unix, wget, centos6

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I'm having an issue...

I need to set up a wget job in CentOS 6.5 that will pull data from two different URLs and then save those two sets of data in two different directories.

Ex:

URL1 > DIRECTORY1
URL2 > DIRECTORY2

I've been trying to do some research into multiple URLs with wget but, there doesn't seem to be much documentation on the process, aside from this ([Wget download list of URL and set different file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006411/wget-download-list-of-url-and-set-different-file-paths)).

Can anyone help me accomplish this seemingly simple Unix task?

Comment: You can try the `--mirror` option, it will create a directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file.sh paste below code

## !/bin/bash

wget http://cdn.seogadget.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/terminal.gif -P /home/trupti/Documents

wget https://d11xdyzr0div58.cloudfront.net/static/vector_tux.864e6cdcce6cdcc23e.png -P /home/trupti

Save the file file.sh
run the command on terminal as ./file.sh